# how can i save a text file without typing ".txt" at the end?

Tags: c++

My Program (c++):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

float x, y, z;
char d[20];

int main()
{   
    cin.getline >>d;
    x=111;
    y=222;
    z=333;
    ofstream meuarquivo;
    meuarquivo.open (d".txt");
    meuarquivo << x << "\n";
    meuarquivo << y << "\n";
    meuarquivo << z << "\n";

    meuarquivo.close ();

    return 0;
}
```

I want to write something like "ThatsMyProgram", and I want the program to save this file as "ThatsMyProgram.txt".  How can I do that?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using a char[] for holding the input, could you not use string from the standard library?

Answer (score 5):

Use `std::string`, which defines `operator +` for concatenation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

int main()
{   
  std::string filename;
  std::getline(std::cin, filename);

  std::ofstream file((filename + ".txt").c_str());

  // use stream here.
}
```

Comment: You need `std::ofstream file((filename + ".txt").c_str())`, unfortunately.

Comment: That will soon be fixed with C++0x. Some compilers have it already.